# Adding existing Visual Studio project to existing Devops project

Tags: azure, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019, devops, azure-repos

I have a project that consists out of two visual studio projects: App and API.
I want to have both of these under the same Devops project, but so far I can only get the App to actually use versioning. Uploading a second project seems to be not possible.

Comment: Are both projects tracked separately in Git? When you say DevOps project do you mean Azure DevOps? Have you tried right clicking the solution in VS and selecting "Add Existing Project"?

Comment: Probably might want to include details about what you mean specifically about versioning.

Comment: @Matt Azure Devops.

Comment: @Parrotmaster I meant what you mean by "App to actually use versioning"

Comment: @Matt The App that I have programmed is hooked up to an Azure Devops project and I can make branches, commits and sync from the VS interface. None of this is true for the API project.

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of how your project is structured within Visual Studio (i.e., within the same solution or otherwise), you can always [create a new repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/create-new-repo?view=azure-devops) within your Azure DevOps project or [connect your local repo to a remote](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/creatingrepo?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio#remotes) to version control it on Azure DevOps.

One project containing multiple repos works well if the products/services are working on a coordinated release schedule. Your decision for one vs. many repos should be largely based on code dependencies and architecture.

Additional resources:

- [Plan your organizational structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/plan-your-azure-devops-org-structure?view=azure-devops)
- [Clone an existing Git repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/clone?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio)